# Can $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ prove that every nonempty c.e. set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has a least element?

Tags: lo.logic, reverse-math, nonstandard-analysis, theories-of-arithmetic

In other words, can $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ prove that for every function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, there is $b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \exists k \in \mathbb{N},\ f(k) = b\quad \land\quad \forall j \in \mathbb{N},\ f(j) \geq b $$

If so, is there a reference to this result? If not, is this result known to be provable/equivalent over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ to another subsystem of SOA, and is there a reference for this?

---

More generally (this is more than I need, but out of interest), we could consider the principles $\mathsf{L}\Sigma^i_n$, $\mathsf{L}\Pi^i_n$, $\mathsf{L}\Delta^i_n$ which say that every $\Sigma^i_n$ / $\Pi^i_n$ / $\Delta^i_n$ definable subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element. Where do these fall in the reverse mathematical hierarchy? Is anything known (even for $i=0$)?

Comment: This is $L\Sigma^0_1$, which is equivalent to $I\Sigma^0_1$, which is included in $\mathrm{RCA}_0$ by definition.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: do you have a reference for the equivalence? I couldn't find it in Simpson's book or online.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett I think this isn't that hard to show directly, but if you want a reference this is Theorem 2.4 in "Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic" by Hájek and Pudlák.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. If you have a direct proof, I'd love to see it.

Comment: So a kind of minimization principle can be found in SOSOA:  II.3.5 on page 70.  I think this answers your question.

Comment: @SamSanders: yes, I saw that, but couldn't quite see how to connect it to my problem. Maybe taking $k=0$?

Answer (score 6):

As Emil Jeřábek and James Hanson mentioned in comments, this is well-known in the literature of first-order arithmetic as the *$\Sigma_1$ least number principle*, $\mathsf{L}\Sigma_1$. Simpson doesn't mention it in his book (he doesn't really talk about $\Sigma_n$ bounding either, which is more well known).

Over $\mathsf{PA}^- + \mathsf{I}\Sigma_0$, Kirby and Paris [1] proved that  $\mathsf{L}\Sigma_n$, $\mathsf{L}\Pi_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Pi_n$ are all equivalent.

Over $\mathsf{PA}^- + \mathsf{I}\Sigma_0 + \mathsf{exp}$, Slaman [2] proved (building on results of Kirby and Paris) that  $\mathsf{L}\Delta_n$, $\mathsf{I}\Delta_n$, $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n$, are all equivalent.

Both reversals hold over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$, since it proves $\mathsf{PA}^- + \mathsf{I}\Sigma_0 + \mathsf{exp}$. In particular, $\mathsf{L}\Sigma_1$ holds in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ (as Emil Jeřábek mentioned).

---

[1] L. A. S. Kirby and J. B. Paris. *$\Sigma_n$-collection schemas in arithmetic.* Angus Macintyre, Leszek Pacholski, Jeff Paris (eds.), *Logic Colloquium '77* (proceedings of colloquium held in Wrocław, August 1977). Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics **96**, pp. 199-209. Elsevier North-Holland, NY, 1978.

[2] Theodore A. Slaman. *$\Sigma_n$-bounding and $\Delta_n$-induction.* Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society **132(8)**, pp. 2449-2456, 2004.